# Lint nested Typescript Generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am looking for a way to correctly express my data model with tyepscript definitions. So far I have the following:

```
type Data = Record<string, string>;

interface DataContainer<D extends Data> { 
    id: string;    
    data: D;
}

interface Context {
    dataContainers: DataContainer<any>[];
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGilIpoD4BuAKHauAlwDM4maPEQBhbJURVehGFAgAPHpXzFYCOMygBvKOygGo5fAC4GZKtVaG9N-BrMwOAX07deAoVHGTFwHfqG9mISUpS8xI4aPmEycJQgzADaALounDiUpFAAtiAxfmYFSigBdtGhcNK4kVBJgTYG2g2NNsZmAEQAjABMAMwdtC2tBsFwZs0jU1AKZl1D0yMgnT2Dw4tQAF4T41BdzgsbrlPHhinsrly%20-ILQALIgIkh%20ECpqT2WGs1DdazbLUB69AA9MCoAAZbjyXC4PAAOigAAoAIJqACSUAA7vF-ORgABKC5AA)

A `Context` stores a set of `DataContainers`, where each `DataContainer` is generic over a specific data structure `D`.  Now what I want to express is that each of those data structures `D` should follow a universal type `Data`. I.e. consisting of arbitrary but fixed `<string, string>` pairs.

I really could not find a proper solution for that, the best thing I found was `DataContainer<D extends Data>`. Do you think that's a good approach?

At least the following gives my a linting error as desired:

```
interface MyData extends Data {
    x: "1",
    y: 2, // Lint error, because not string. (As I want it)
}
```

So I conclude that when writing `<D extends Data>` it would also not be allowed for `D` to have an entry like `y: 2`, correct?

Now a real problem for me is that the following does *not* give me a linting error:

```
const myContext: Context = {
    dataContainers: [
        {
            id: "123",
            data: {
                x: 1, // This should be marked by the linter
                y: "2", 
                z: {a: 1}, // This also
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for a way to model my definitions such that a linter would mark this as invalid, because there exists no `D` such that the above would be a valid Context. Is that possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Notpick: TS is a language not a linter :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The issue is with `DataContainer<any>`. Any effectively turns off type checking where it is used. This means that since `data` in  `DataContainer<any>` will be of type `any`, no checks will be done for the property. This is regardless of the constraint you put on `D`

The simple solution is to not use `any`, use the constraint as the type argument to `DataContainer`:

```
interface Context {
    dataContainers: DataContainer<Data>[];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGilIpoD4BuAKHauAlwDM4maPEQBhbJURVehGFAgAPHpXzFYCOMygBvKOygGo5fAC4GZKtVaG9N-BrMwOAX07deAoVHGTFwHfqG9mISUpS8xI4aPmEyIpoA2gC6LpzsOJSkUAC2IDF+ZvlKKAF20aFw0riRUAmBNgba9Q02xmYARACMAEwAzO20zS0GwXBmTcOTUApmnfQA9PO8uENTBiAd3QNQi1DYANarawBe42NQnc4L8-K4K2sGrpNPhknszkA)

Comment: Thank you! That did it for me!